# How to add form validation echo before result echo

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form in php which works just fine, except that the user can see result without providing email and name fields. I want to add a php code that will echo to user that name and email is required before he gets to see the final answer. I have tried adding various if and else statements but the form stops working if i fiddle with the code. I would b really grateful for some help

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['fieldname5_1'];
$email = $_POST['fieldname6_1'];
$score = $_POST['fieldname158_1'];
if(empty($name) || empty($email))
{
echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";

}
else {
if($score<"6") {
echo " something1 $score";
} elseif($score<"11") {
echo " something2 $score";
} elseif($score<"30") {
echo " something3 $score";
} elseif($score<"81") {
echo " something4 $score";
}  else {
echo " something5 $score";
}
}
$formcontent="something6 $score";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com, $email";
$subject = "Your test";
$mailheader = "From: myemail@email.com \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this html form u can add "required" to input? or  in js if form submited check fields , if all ok, your POST will go to php action/method

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. I have made the edits and things are working. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You have broken the logic of `if` `else`, I suggest you to perform some checks at startup with `isset` (`empty` is not enought, it doesn't exclude the case of vars `isset`) and if not set then `print` a message using `exit()` to ensure that the full code is not being executed... now sanitize your input using `htmlentities` with `UTF-8` that protect your code from `XSS` and `Injection`... then add the mail `headers` to ensure that your mail will be sent... checking with `boolean` if your mail is sent or not... add the `5th parameter` (`-f`) to your mail to ensure your mail will be forced sent correctly... below you can see my fixes...

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fieldname5_1"><br/>
Mail: <input type="text" name="fieldname6_1"><br/>
Score: <input type="number" name="fieldname158_1"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php
if ((!isset($_POST['fieldname5_1']) || (empty($_POST['fieldname5_1']))) || (!isset($_POST['fieldname6_1']) || (empty($_POST['fieldname6_1'])))) {
  exit("Enter a valid name and mail!");
} elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*'.'@([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+))+$/', $_POST['fieldname6_1'])) {
  exit("Provide a valid email address!");
} else {
  $name = htmlentities($_POST['fieldname5_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $email = htmlentities($_POST['fieldname6_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if ((!isset($_POST['fieldname158_1']) || (empty($_POST['fieldname158_1'])))) {
  exit("Please enter your vote!");
} else {
  $score = htmlentities($_POST['fieldname158_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if ((isset($score)) && ($score < 6)) {
  echo " something1 $score";
} elseif ((isset($score)) && ($score < 11)) {
  echo " something2 $score";
} elseif ((isset($score)) && ($score < 30)) {
  echo " something3 $score";
} elseif ((isset($score)) && ($score < 81)) {
  echo " something4 $score";
} elseif (isset($score)) {
  echo " something5 $score";
}
$formcontent = "something6 $score";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com, $email";
$subject = "Your test";
$mailheader = "From: myemail@email.com" . PHP_EOL;
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=\"UTF-8\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mailheader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
if (!@mail($recipient, $ubject, $formcontent, $mailheader, "-f$recipient")) {
  echo("Mail Sent!");
} else {
  echo("Mail Not Sent!");
}
?>
```

Sorry but I can't understand what you're actually trying to get out of your code. I interpreted your desires but I don't know if that's what you asked for because reading your code everything is approximate. I hope I satisfied you.

Hope this helps.